# Bootstrap Colorpicker Add-on for Separate Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use [Bootstrap Colorpicker](https://farbelous.github.io/bootstrap-colorpicker/) to control the color of text from an input field.  I want the add-on field attached to an input field but not the default associated hex input box.

Specifically, I have a text input field for Title and I want an add-on Colorpicker box next to the field that will govern its color (as displayed elsewhere).  I can't figure out how to just use the Colorpicker add-on box without the standard hex input field.

*How do I properly code an add-on for an unrelated input field and still retain the value in JS for use elsewhere?*

Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <!-- Style -->
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal" action="process-campaign-creative.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="control-label">
      Title
    </label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title">

    <!-- PROBLEM HERE: Doesn't show color box (and value doesn't seem to change) -->
    <span id="cp1" class="input-group-addon colorpicker-component" value="#00AABB"><i></i></span>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
//SRC: https://github.com/farbelous/bootstrap-colorpicker/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#cp1').colorpicker();
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
//SRC: https://github.com/farbelous/bootstrap-colorpicker/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should match the color inside input tag, not inside span

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-group colorpicker-component ">
   <input type="text" value="#00AABB" class="form-control"/>
   <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
 $('.colorpicker-component').colorpicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to apply the selected color DIRECTLY on the input field content.
(which contains user's text for a "title", not an hex color number).

Okay... But BootStrap's colorPicker actually uses the `input` field to select a color using the keyboard.

**So we have to *"hack it"* a little...**
The good thing is that we can unbind the input's `keyup` event from colorPicker.

We'll then have to ensure the user's text will remain on colorPicker's `changeColor` event... And get the color number [directly from the API (using `.data('colorpicker')`)](https://farbelous.github.io/bootstrap-colorpicker/) to apply it to the user's text.

So here is the code as you wished it to act: *(Run the snippet)*

```js
$(function() {
  
  // Initiate the colorpicker
  $("#cp").colorpicker();

  // Unbind the keyup event from the input (which normally changes the color.)
  $("#title").off("keyup");
  
  // Define a variable for the user's text at global scope.
  var titleText;

  // Get the text value inputed by the user as soon as the colorPicker is accessed.
  $('#cp-icon').on("mousedown",function(){
    titleText = $("#cp>input").val();
    //console.log( titleText );
  });
  
  // On color selection, affect the input's text with it.
  $("#cp").on("changeColor",function(){
    //console.log("change event");
    var colorPicked = $('#cp').data('colorpicker').input[0].value;
    $("#title").val(titleText).css("color",colorPicked);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.1/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.1/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="process-campaign-creative.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="control-label">
          Title
        </label>
        <div class="input-group" id="cp">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title">
          <span class="input-group-addon colorpicker-component"><i id="cp-icon"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Same on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/dRNxgE?editors=1011).